# Normalize the espicific rows of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with size ( 6*1000) I want to normalize it based on this rule:
Normalize the rows 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, ... (6*i for i in range(1000)) based on the formulation which I provide.
Dont change the values of the other rows.
Here is an example:

```
def normalize(array):
    minimum = np.expand_dims(np.min(array, axis=1), axis=1)
    maximum = np.expand_dims(np.max(array, axis=1), axis=1)
    return (array - minimum) / (maximum - minimum + 0.00001)
```

Calling with the following input doesn't work:

```
A = array([[15, 14,  3],
   [11,  9,  9],
   [16,  6,  1],
   [14,  6,  9],
   [ 1, 12,  2],
   [ 5,  1,  2],
   [13, 11,  2],
   [11,  4,  1],
   [11,  7, 10],
   [10, 11, 16],
   [ 2, 13,  4],
   [12, 14, 14]])

normalize(A)
```

I expect the following output:

```
array([[0.99999917, 0.9166659 , 0.    ],
   [11,  9,  9],
   [16,  6,  1],
   [14,  6,  9],
   [ 1, 12,  2],
   [ 5,  1,  2],
   [0.99999909, 0.81818107, 0.        ]],
   [11,  4,  1],
   [11,  7, 10],
   [10, 11, 16],
   [ 2, 13,  4],
   [12, 14, 14]])
```

Comment: does `array[::6] = normalize(array[::6])` work? if not, could you explain more what the issue you're facing is?

Comment: thanks for the comment. it changed the 6*i to 0.

Comment: that seems like an issue with normalize though... tbh I'm a bit confused by the expand dims. could you describe in words what you're trying to do?

Comment: also... is there a purpose to the `a` definition in the first line? that looks like it's not used anywhere

Comment: The a is only provided to check for a simple test. The normalization is also based on maximum and minimum of each rows. So, I want to change each number of row (0 for example) to ( value-minimum of row 0)/maximum of row 0-minimum of row 0)

Comment: rather than adding context in comments, can you [edit] your question to clarify it? also, take another look at the [formatting guide](/help/formatting) and make sure your question is as easy to read and as clear as possible so others can help too. thanks!

Comment: and I don't mean `A`, I mean `a`, which as far as I can tell isn't used anywhere

Comment: You need to cast the original array to float dtype first: `array = array.astype('float')`, then do `array[::6] = normalize(array[::6])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up a second function having the `step` argument:

```py
def normalize_with_step(array, step):
    
    b = normalize(array[::step])
    a, b = list(array), list(b)
    
    for i in range(0, len(a), step):
        a[i] = b[int(i/step)]
        
    a = np.array(a)
    return a
```

Let's try it with a `step = 6`:

```py
a = np.random.randint(17, size = (12, 3))
a = normalize_with_step(a, 6)
a
```

**Output**

```py
array([[ 0.83333264,  0.99999917,  0.        ],
       [ 9.        , 14.        ,  6.        ],
       [14.        , 15.        , 12.        ],
       [12.        ,  7.        , 10.        ],
       [ 8.        , 13.        ,  9.        ],
       [12.        ,  0.        ,  3.        ],
       [ 0.53333298,  0.99999933,  0.        ],
       [15.        , 14.        , 12.        ],
       [14.        ,  6.        , 16.        ],
       [ 9.        , 14.        ,  3.        ],
       [ 8.        ,  9.        ,  0.        ],
       [10.        , 13.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: this should do the same thing as, but would be much slower than, `A[::step] = normalize(A[::step])`

Comment: Writing only `A[::step] = normalize(A[::step])` doesn't give the desired output, so it's part of the function as you can see `b = normalize(array[::step])` in the first line of my function, the function returns the array with `normalized` item at the desired step

Comment: But that’s an issue with normalize. It doesn’t mean you should turn the whole array into a python list…

Comment: Where's the issue? since we get the desired output when we apply `normalize_with_step` function. If you search a magic solution by writing a single line code instead of a function let me know please

Comment: Thanks for your response. I accepted this response, but I think the solution which @bui provided is more faster and easier.

Comment: yeah the major difference is just performance. for a larger array (I tested with an array with 10 million rows), `normalize(a.astype(float)[::6])` is 50 times faster than `normalize_with_step`